# xperf trace of ATI driver causing a 1 minute freeze while changing resolution

Tags: windows-7, freeze, amd-radeon, xperf

I've recently been getting complete hangs (black screen, music stops, cursor won't move, etc.) of over a minute when locking my machine, or changing resolution.

It only starts happening after a while (i.e. rebooting fixes it), and once it starts it doesn't seem to ever go away.  It's really inconvenient, but not the end of the world; I'm more interested in attributing blame.  It's incredibly hard to search for the problem as I don't have reproduction steps.   It may have only started happening after I started using three monitors (on the same card).

Others' versions of this problem seem less severe, and/or triggered by remote desktop (don't use), full-screen applications (like games) (don't use), suspending (which I do daily and doesn't (directly) cause it), etc.

I've run:

```
xperf -on Latency -stackwalk profile
[change resolution]
xperf -d foo
```

.. which is available: http://b.goeswhere.com/res-stac2.7z [8mb, extracts to 90mb] (yes, I'm aware of the privacy warnings involved in posting this).

The best I can get out of xperf (screenshot actually of a different dump) is:

[image]

Is more information available that I'm missing?  I have symbol paths configured well enough for WinDbg, and the stackwalk registry settings enabled.

Is there anything I can do towards the diagnosis of this issue beyond a remote kernel debug (local kernel debugging is out due to the machine being unusable)?

Win7 x64 Ultimate legit sp1, ATI Radeon HD 5830, happened across multiple ATI driver versions including 11.3 (11.4 is current, sigh).  Basically no software that could interfere (i.e. no firewall/av besides Windows defaults and MSE).

Comment: Did you try a clean boot, see if the problem persists?...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331796/en-us

Comment: You don't have your symbols set, right click in the summary table and inform it to load the symbols and look up on the internet how to set them correctly if it still doesn't load.

Answer (score 2):

The last identifiable call is **DisableAllPrimaries**, where it hands over to the **ATI driver** to call what I think would be a **shutdown** procedure so it can properly reinitialize the video card afterwards. So, as the actually problem resides in the ATI driver I would suggest you to **update your video drivers**. :)